# Using observeOn() the Android UI thread crashes my emulator testing

Tags: java, android, android-studio, rx-java, rx-android

When I use RxAndroid and `.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())`, and run tests on an emulator using Android Studio, the whole test run crashes with:

> Instrumentation run failed due to '`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError`'

and `logcat` output like the following:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fatal Exception thrown on Scheduler.Worker thread.
       at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:54)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.lazySet
       at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:46)
       ... 9 more
Error in app net.tbmcv.rxtest running instrumentation ComponentInfo{net.tbmcv.rxtest.test/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner}:
  java.lang.NoSuchMethodError
  java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.lazySet
Force stopping package net.tbmcv.rxtest uid=10042
```

Neither Android Studio nor the `logcat` output mention any lines of code in my project or my tests. Here are some relevant parts of a short example project I created that reproduces this crash:

#### `app/build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:0.24.0'
}
```

#### `MainActivity.java`

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public void setTitleFrom(Observable<String> observable) {
        observable.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Action1<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void call(String s) {
                        setTitle(s);
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

#### `MainActivityFuncTest.java`

```
public class MainActivityFuncTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MainActivity> {
    public void testSetTitle() {
        final String newTitle = "Hello World";
        getActivity().setTitleFrom(Observable.just(newTitle));
        getInstrumentation().waitForIdleSync();
        assertEquals(newTitle, getActivity().getTitle());
    }
}
```

My test runs correctly if I modify my `MainActivity` code to not use `observeOn()`:

```
public void setTitleFrom(Observable<String> observable) {
    observable.subscribe(new Action1<String>() {
        @Override
        public void call(final String s) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    setTitle(s);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

But I'd rather use `observeOn()`, because it's cleaner and more modular. How can I get my tests to run?

My emulator is running API version 8 (Android 2.2).

Comment: There seems to be a version error in the emulator. AtomicReference.lazySet is a pretty standard Java 6 method.

Comment: @akarnokd thanks, that's it! My emulator was running API 8, and RxJava only works on API 9+. RxAndroid's page doesn't mention API version restrictions at all, I guess because it's already mentioned on the RxJava page. Want to write an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Use `io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.0.1`

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky would that truly work around the Android version incompatibility described in the answer below?

Comment: @DanGetz Good question.  I was just making an observation about your build.gradle file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [RxJava's GitHub page](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava), RxJava versions 1.0.x only work on Android 2.3 or later (corresponding to API 9 or later). RxAndroid depends on RxJava, of course, so the same restriction applies (even though it's currently not mentioned on the RxAndroid page.)

The above tests run fine on an emulator running a more recent version of Android.